# Run a List<CompletableFuture> One After Another

Tags: java, completable-future

So I have an interface `SetupTask` that has only a single method `run()` which returns a `CompletableFuture`. I have a `List<SetupTask>`. I want to run the first one and when that is complete run the second and when that is complete run the third and so on. Originally I tried `CompletableFuture.allOf()` but that would run them all in parallel.

Comment: A `CompletableFuture` is not something you _run_ so it's unclear what you are asking.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis You're right, so I am running a method that returns a CompletableFuture, I want to run the next one when the previous one is finished.

Comment: Then trigger the 2nd by chaining it to the completion of the CF.

Comment: Do you initially call this method in loop?

Comment: It would be great if you showed how you create that list and call the method

Comment: I am going to add some to the post in a second.

Comment: @KirillSimonov hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 4):

You could chain all these tasks one after another consistently calling [.thenCompose](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#thenCompose-java.util.function.Function-). This method executes some function that returns a `CompletableFuture` when the given stage is complete. I used `CompletableFuture<Void>` just to demonstrate how it would look like.

```
CompletableFuture<Void> current = CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null);
for (SetupTask task : tasks) {
    current = current.thenCompose(v -> task.run());
}
```